# Sitecore Lighthouse Setup

Tags: docker, lighthouse

We are trying to Setup Lighthouse(https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Demo.Platform/blob/main/docs/Usage.md) environment on Azure VM

We were able to execute all the steps to provision Demo environment until it came down to last step(Please see screenshot below) which is provisioning of entire Sitecore app. We see that some containers are running for the past 2 hrs and not getting started. This is what it's showing in Powershell Console

```
Container Sitecore xp0-smtp-1(Running -0 Sec)

Container Sitecore xp0-solr-1(Running -0 Sec)

Container Sitecore xp0-mssql-1(Running -0 Sec)

Container Sitecore xp0-connect-1(Running -0 Sec)

Container Sitecore xp0-ps-1(Started -22 Sec)
```

Rest of them are all running

Can someone please help to understand why some of the Container services are not getting started?

Comment: Did you forget to add the screenshot?

Comment: I have also faced a similar issue but when I stopped unwanted services running and clean up enough disk space. Then all services are started running.

Comment: Thanks issue is resolved.i cleaned dockers containers and it worked